# User intended to delete post but did not delete post

Tags: discussion

I received an answer to a question that made assumptions about my problem that were incorrect and the user who posted it has since recognized that they were misguided. However, instead of deleting their post they have used `<strike>` to cross out their answer.

I believe, but of course can't be certain, that the user intended to delete his or her post. What would the appropriate flag be to raise on this answer or how could one best handle this situation?

Link to post:
[Format string for date invalid when converting to decimal day and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186318/format-string-for-date-invalid-when-converting-to-decimal-day-and-month)

Comment: Considering how much harder it is to strike out an answer than to delete it, I'd be pretty confident in stating they know how to delete it and choose not to.

Comment: @Servy what purpose would that serve though? I guess I would just like to understand a thought process that could lead to such behavior

Comment: If you want to know why they did a thing it's going to be more productive to ask them why the did the thing than to ask us why they did the thing.

Comment: I'd probably just revert the edit and @ them in the comment, reminding them that deleting things is the correct way to handle such things. If they persist, probably flag a mod to handle things.

Comment: @servy you are right. I was wondering if maybe there was a feature that didn't allow an answer to be removed for some reason

Comment: @RyanSchaefer The only situation where that would be true would be if it were accepted, which it's not here.  As a PSA, if there is an accepted answer of yours that you know is wrong, but cannot delete it due to it being accepted, flag the post for a moderator to deleted, explaining that you now know it's wrong but can't delete it due to it being accepted, and they should delete it for you.

Answer (score 1):

> What would the appropriate flag be to raise on this answer

Wrong answers should not be flagged for being wrong in the first place, regardless of the content (unless it's offensive). That's what the rating system is for. A badly formatted and wrong answer will eventually be downvoted and be moved to the bottom.

What you could have done is inform the answerer of your assumption in a comment below their answer and see if they delete it themselves. Other than that you could flag for **very low quality**:

> This answer has severe **formatting or content problems**. This answer is
>   unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.